# Change color of particular location in tab control

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a `tab-control` with `DrawMode` set to `OwnerDrawFixed`. I want it that when the mouse moves over a particular location in the `tab-control` the color of the location should be changed. I have tried using `Rectangle` but i'm stuck at how to change the color of the `Rectangle`.

This is what i have.

```
    private void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.tabControl1.TabPages.Count; i++)
        {
            Rectangle r = tabControl1.GetTabRect(i);
            Rectangle closeButton = new Rectangle(r.Right - 15, r.Top + 4, 12, 12);
            if (closeButton.Contains(e.Location))
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT :** `DrawItem` Code

```
    private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("x", e.Font, Brushes.Red, e.Bounds.Right-16, e.Bounds.Top+4);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + 12, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

My question is, how do i color the rectangle and if it is not possible, what other way can i use?.

Comment: You will have to call tabControl1.Invalidate() to force a repaint.  Keep track of which tab should be painted with a different color with a variable.

Comment: @HansPassant Please can u give an example. I have no clue at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to call the tab control's Invalidate() method to force a repaint.  Something like this:

```
private int activeButton = -1;

private void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int button;
    for (button = this.tabControl1.TabPages.Count-1; button >= 0; button--)
    {
        Rectangle r = tabControl1.GetTabRect(button);
        Rectangle closeButton = new Rectangle(r.Right - 15, r.Top + 4, 12, 12);
        if (closeButton.Contains(e.Location)) break;
    }
    if (button != activeButton) {
        activeButton = button;
        tabControl1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

And use the activeButton variable in your DrawItem event handler to determine if you need to draw it with a different color.

Comment: I think you mistyped `i` with `button`?

Comment: Why not just use the MouseEnter/Leave events?  Plus the Rectangle in this code is not a control you can 'colour' its a dimension/size property.

Comment: Because he only wants to color the button if the mouse is located near the right of the tab button, where he draws the close glyph.  And you can certainly color it any way you want with owner-draw.

Comment: @HansPassant Now i'm even more confused. Pls How do i use the `activeButton` Variable in my `DrawItem` event handler?

Comment: @HansPassant I have posted it

Comment: Arbitrarily: `if (e.Index == activeButton) e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, e.Bounds); `

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `GetTabRect` doesn't do what you've thought it does.  It gets the bounding rectangle of the control, which is the size of a rectangle that completely encloses the control.  This isn't a 'control' that has a colour etc its a property of the `TabControl`.

As I've understood your question you've got lots of controls on the tab and you want to highlight some of them when the mouse is over them?

If so the easiest way is to use a container control (`FlowLayoutPanel`, `Panel`, `SplitContainer`, `TableLayoutPanel`) and place your controls in that.

I've created a basic form with a tab control and a panel control on the tab.  The following code changes the background colour when the mouse enters or leaves the panel control edges.  You don't need to wire up the `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave` events in code if you don't want to...the designer will show you which controls have these events and wire them up in the `InitializeComponent()` code.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        panel1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(panel1_MouseEnter);
        panel1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(panel1_MouseLeave);
    }

    void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    void panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.BackColor = Color.PaleGoldenrod;
    }
```

If I've misunderstood and you want to highlight the actual `TabControl` some how then, as this control doesn't have any colour properties at all, you will need to either put the TabControl inside another control (like Panel), or as suggested manually draw on the form (within the OnPaint event).  I wouldn't recommend this route as it can get quite complicated and can have lots of performance issues.